# Set "hints" for function name

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

I'm trying to declare function named hints and it does not work.

```
function hints() {
    alert("E");
}

<select id = "cbTipo" onchange="hints();">
    <option value = 0>1</option>
    <option value = 1>2</option>
</select>
```

Is it a reserved word?

Comment: maybe it is how you add it to the page... What is the exact error message?

Comment: Did you surround it with `script` tags?

Comment: Put your function inside script tag , because i copy pasted the code and it works properly

Comment: dloeda Yes, inside script tag, other name work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to surround your JS code with `script` tags.

```html
<select id = "cbTipo" onchange="hints();">
    <option value = 0>1</option>
    <option value = 1>2</option>
</select>

<script>
function hints() {
    alert("E");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript reserverd words: https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_reserved.asp
'Hints' - is not the reserved word